# Lyx instant preview in Fedora 29

Tags: lyx, linuxfedora

I recently did a fresh install of Fedora 29 Workstation on my laptop with Lyx 2.3.2 installed. In working with previous Lyx documents, I needed to add different .sty files to get things to work, so I did a `sudo dnf install texlive-scheme-full` but this installed way more than I needed. So I removed this `texlive-scheme-full` and just installed the packages I needed (`texlive-cancel` and `texlive-braket`). But now my instant preview isn't working. Looking at https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/InstantPreview I installed all the packages listed that I need for instant preview to work, all except `preview-latex` because I can't seem to find that in the Fedora repos. I did find the `tex-preview` package and installed that, but the instant preview looked awful. Is there another package I need to install to make instant preview look like it first did when having `tex-preview` installed, or is there some other package I can install to get things working again?

Update after KJO's latest advice:

I downloaded the preview.zip folder, ran `tex preview.ins` and placed all the files in the `/texmf/tex/latex/` directory and Lyx now shows the instant preview. However, the rendering looks pretty bad. Maybe there's a way to make the rendering look better?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are following this guide https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/InstantPreview

The Preview package is related to preview-latex as used by auctex BUT is effectively a generic subset it is the standard **preview package** that should be loaded using TeX Live ManaGeR I do not know Unix well enough to advise with confidence but if you used sudo for texlive would guess you need something along the lines of `sudo tlmgr install preview` **however I suggest you test** with `sudo tlmgr install --dryrun preview` per the following guide to check it will work https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#install-option...-pkg

If you have a GUI access to tlmgr (which requires the perl components) you can filter a package search to see if it is already installed. see https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#GUI-FOR-TLMGR

Once it is downloaded you will need to consider if you need to run `sudo texhash`  to update filename/directory database files

If you cannot use tlmgr then the uncompiled file is available here and will need to be run through TeX http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/preview.zip

> To install the preview style file on its own without the entire AUCTeX
>   package, run
>
> ```
> tex preview.ins
> ```
>
> If preview.ins happens to be missing, you can regenerate it by running
>   tex docstrip on preview.dtx with the option `installer'.
>
> **Running TeX on preview.ins will then extract further files:** preview.drv which you can run through LaTeX in order to get the
>   documentation for preview.sty, preview.sty itself, a bunch of option
>   files with extension .def and a few configuration files with extension
>   .cfg.  In case your docstrip configuration has not already taken care
>   of that, install the files with extension .sty, .def and .cfg to a
>   location where LaTeX will be able to find them.

The location as mentioned can be either your working folder alongside the tex file you are editing or in the correct relative location on a texmf tree.
Thus wherever your …/texmf is in the texmf/tex/latex you need a /preview/  folder with the preview.sty 8x filename.def (especially the LyX one) and the prauctex.cfg (though in this LyX case unsure if that's essential)If it is in the correct position lyx will find it and in Help > Latex configuration > in my version it is **9.27 preview** it should show **Found: [yes]**
Note in my manual it is not the correct path for the switch in my version its in Tools > Look & Feel **Display** then tick Display graphics  & ensure **Instant preview On** note you can also add scaling like this

[image]

Your quality may differ depending on settings and packages for support from the "Additional" help page the default formats can result in rougher image rendering. Document settings > Formats > defaults to PDF (pdfLaTeX) and generally does not need the external shell escape active but your mileage may vary, the XHTML Options are by default set strict XHTML and math output should be MathML but from the help we see section 4.1 that if those are unsupported by the system it will default to image rendering Quality is also affected as per user guide  section 6.12.1 Prerequisites Results should be better if pnmcrop is available from netpbm package.

Comment: It doesn't look like Fedora comes with or has access to tlmgr. So this option might not be viable for me.

Comment: If you stripped to the bone without the basics of a manager there may not be enough to compile the preview since the minimal TeX Live should have some maintenance utilities, otherwise the few packages you have will likely error for lack of a supporting framework fedora info is sparse (much of it old) but a recent link here suggests a recommendation for [starters](https://fedoramagazine.org/fedora-classroom-latex-101-beginners/) of `sudo dnf install texlive-latex` for now you can skip bibtex and git I note the old method was `yum install texlive texlive-latex` but unsure if they include basics

Comment: So I've already installed `texlive-latex` and have actually been looking at [link](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/TeXLive) for how Fedora packages TeX Live. I don't want to do the full scheme because this uses so much space. I just tried installing the small scheme, but it doesn't look like this contains the packages for Lyx's instant preview.

Comment: Am updating end of question to show direct link to preview source files (dtx and ins in a zip) but do not know how you will process on fedora as you need to run them through a tex command to build the sty config etc

Comment: I was able to get things working following your instructions, but the preview looks pretty bad, compared to what I've had in the past. I'll update my question to see what it looks like. Is there a way to get better rendering of the instant preview?

Comment: how does it compare to my simple example where its inflated 2x and still looks ok but I did note that some related text in other fonts (non math ?)became "blocky" There was mention of an improvement option so will revisit that section

Comment: I was able to get 2x zoom on a simple fraction like a/b but mine looks much worse than yours does.

Comment: I was able to figure out the font rendering. I needed to do `sudo dnf install texlive-collection-fontutils` which gave the packages needed to make the instant preview look like normal.

Comment: Glad you got there. that makes sense as there are a large number of font dependencies listed in the Latex configuration but difficult to check which affect since many of mine are listed no (not generally required) and it would take some time to remove those that say yes to see which are critical fontutils probably modifies / builds some of those